# JSON parsing error WCF

Tags: json, wcf

I am working on WCF application, I am invoking this operation

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuditDataService
{

    [OperationContract(Name = "UserAuthentication")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "/UserAuthentication?username={username}")]
    string UserAuthentication(string username, UserData userInfo); 

}
```

I am getting error

```
"Object Reference not set to an instance"
```

here

```
public string UserAuthentication(string username, UserData userInfo)
 {
  string outputData = string.Empty;
  return userInfo.ToString(); // << Error at this line 
 }
```

Here is the JSON Class

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable()]
public class UserData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "UserName", Order = 1)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Password", Order = 2)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Token", Order = 3)]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Here is JSON request via POST method

```
{"UserName":"abcd",
"Password":"1234",
"Token":"1234"}
```

Here is response screen shot [image]

Any Help !

Comment: userInfo is null. Where are you getting that value from?

Comment: I have edit it , Kindly check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BodyStyle` property of your `[WebInvoke]` attribute specifies the style to be `WrappedRequest` - which means that the object which you want passed as the input must be *wrapped* in an object, whose member name is the same as the property name, as Steve Wilkes mentioned.

Another alternative would be to change the `BodyStyle` to `Bare`; in this case your input should work just fine. In other words, if this is your operation declaration, the input you have in your question should work.

```
[OperationContract(Name = "UserAuthentication")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate = "/UserAuthentication?username={username}")]
string UserAuthentication(string username, UserData userInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but shouldn't you be posting:

```
{
    username: "abcd"
    userInfo: {
        "UserName": "abcd",
        "Password": "1234",
        "Token": "1234"
    }
}
```

...?

Comment: He is getting the `username` from request url. Check `UriTemplate`. So, only `{userInfo:{...}}` of your solution should do it.

Comment: Still having same issue. It is giving me bad request Error , which is due to "Object Reference not set to an instance"

Comment: My bad on the `username` - thanks for pointing it out - I was too lazy to scroll :)